# How to defensively create Rx Observables and avoid race conditions?

Tags: swift, concurrency, rx-swift, defensive-programming

I was hunting a weird edge case where a list of files in a directory didn't show results for 0...2 files but worked fine for 3...n files.

It turned out that the original observable sequence worked just fine. But I used a `PublishSubject` in one subscriber to relay the effect of the change. All of this reportedly happened on the main queue, but it seems the `PublishSubject` got fed values before it had a subscriber. (Since there's no replay, the subscriber wouldn't know.)

So the set-up of all components (origin -- relaying subscriber -- consuming subscriber) seems to have introduced *time* as a problem.

Weird observations:

- If I make the original `Observable` a `Driver`, things work fine.
- If I insert `.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)` somewhere in the original chain (before the relaying subscriber), things work fine. Even though I can see through the use of breakpoints in map operations that the mapping happens on `com.apple.main-queue (serial)` already.
- If I use `.subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)` at the origin or in the subscriber's code, I still get the problem. (Probably because at the origin it only affects the relaying subscriber, and later it's too late.)

Now I don't understand how to handle issues like these defensively.

It seems the `PublishSubject` might not be a good fit for the situation. But why does observing-on the main queue improve the situation?

**When should you (defensively) specify observable sequences to run on the main queue *upon creation/production*?** (Again, this might be a pragmatic fix, but it only accidentally seems to solve the problem.)

Or, put differently, **when should you assume things don't happen in time in the consumer's code**, i.e. when the subscription is set up?

There was no way for me to tell that relaying events from input sequence to `PublishSubject` caused trouble. It's not perceivable. Leaves me puzzled how to avoid bugs like this.

Comment: You are talking about hot vs. cold observables (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables). The problem isn't about threads or/and time, but the fact that you emit items before there is someone subscribed to the observable. Two solutions that come in mind: a) emit signals only after subscription (cold observable) or b) add replay to the chain (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html)

Comment: Yeah, it boils down to that. Subscribing to the cold observable and emitting notification events through `PublishSubject` seems to make the thing I consume "hot" in the end. I didn't notice this in my own code; how would I make the hot/cold distinction obvious for others? Is there a naming convention folks adhere to, or do you need to get surprised first when you consume signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the difference of `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` and the properties of `Driver` sequence.

**observeOn** affects the observation blocks i.e. where you handle the emitted values e.g.

```
someObservable
.subscribe(onNext: { /* this is an example of observation block */ })
```

**subscribeOn** affects the scheduler in the subscription block i.e.
where the values are produced e.g.

```
Observable<Int>.create { /* this is an example of subscription block */ }
```

#### Driver

Driver is a special type of observable sequence with some properties.

- Drivers never fail i.e. there is no `onError` events
- Drivers add `.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)` to the sequence
- Drivers share the sequence using `.share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)` operator

Considering the last two you can do your own driver from observable:

```
someObservable
.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
.share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)
```

and this is what you probably want to do by your question.

Comment: Thanks -- 4 years later, I've a way better understanding of that part. Sadly, I don't remember how exactly I introduced the problem. Might be that the subscription ran on a BG queue but this detail was not apparent? Anyway, enjoy the points for accepted answer :)